# What is the OSX ruler clipboard?

Tags: macos

I ran `man pbcopy` which listed the flag `-pboard` with options `{general | ruler | find | font}`.  I understand what the general, find, and font clipboards are, but I can't find any documentation on what use the ruler clipboard has.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ruler` pasteboard, or `NSRulerPboard` [at the programming level](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSPasteboard_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSRulerPboard), is:

> The pasteboard that holds information about paragraph formats in support of the Copy Ruler and Paste Ruler commands that may be implemented in a text editor.

You can read much more about the [Pasteboard here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Devpedia-CocoaApp-MOSX/Pasteboard.html).