# What are the different OS X clipboards

Tags: macos, terminal, keyboard, copy-paste

Everybody uses the general OS X clipboard, which can programmatically accessed with `pbcopy -general` and `pbpaste -general`.
However I noticed that the manpage of `pbcopy` and `pbpaste` also mention:

- `-find` pasteboard
- `-font` pasteboard
- `-ruler` pasteboard

Which all seem to function. But how can they be accessed outside of the terminal? And if not, why do they have these descriptive names?

I also noticed that there is yet another clipboard in OS X. Go to the start of a line of text and press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>.
Now go somewhere else and press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Y</kbd>. You just yanked some text from a clipboard which is none of the above, as they are all still intact. What's up with that?

Comment: The kill ring is a hangover from Emacs - https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Deletion-and-Killing.html#Deletion-and-Killing idk about the others.

Comment: Have a look at the [Pasteboard Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PasteboardGuide106/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008100-SW1) and more specifically [Named Pasteboards](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PasteboardGuide106/Articles/pbConcepts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008101-SW2).

Comment: Is there any way to access the access the kill ring programmatically?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the OSX ruler clipboard?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/232721/what-is-the-osx-ruler-clipboard)

Comment: @MCCCS that isn't really a complete answer either, as it only explains one of these special paste boards. However after knowing one you can kind of infer the others